# Ember Mirage: route answered only if debugger is ran

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I'm facing a weird issue with Ember mirage. I try to use it inside an integration test.

The code looks like this:

```
moduleForComponent('editors/steps/call-handler', 'Integration | Component | editors/steps/call handler', {
  integration: true,

  beforeEach: function () {
    startApp();
    this.server = startMirage();
    ...
  },

  afterEach: function () {
    this.server.shutdown();
  }
});


test('...', function (assert) {
  ...

  this.server.post('/projects/12/actionwords/1/switch/', () => {
    assert.ok(true, "switch route is called");

    return {
      ... some JSON data
    }
  });

  this.render(hbs`{{editors/steps/call-handler
                    ...
                  }}`);

  ... and then some manipulation of the component
});
```

Now the test fails when I run it this way. The weird part is, if I place a debugger just before rendering the component, the test will pass.

I guess there are some timeout issues sooner or later that the debugger hides. Usually, I would only render the component in a callback to ensure the route has been correctly setup but this.server.post returns nothing not has any callbacks (except if I missed something in the doc).

I also tried setting the timing option (just in case) but it doesn't change anything (as expected).

I also tried to add an homemade sleep function to wait one second without the debugger and then the tests work fine. Of course if I can have a clean way to get them working, I'd prefer ;)

Did anyone face the same kind of issues and found a way to solve it ?

Best regards,
Vincent

Comment: Did you try to call the Mirage endpoints from an acceptance test ? If yes, do you have the same error ?

Comment: We have some acceptance tests and they get their responses from Mirage without any issues.

Comment: Ok. Did you try to place the `this.server = startMirage();` before the `startApp();` in the beforeEach function ?

Comment: I've just tried it but same thing, my requests get a 404 response until I let the sleep(1000) call :/